# R : How to write an XYZ file from a SpatialPointsDataFrame?

Tags: r, spatial

I have a SpatialPointsDataFrame which has one attribute (let's call it z for convenience) as well as lat/long coordinates.

I want to write this out to an XYZ file (i.e. an ASCII file with three columns).

Initially I tried

```
write.table(spdf, filename, row.names=FALSE)
```

but this wrote the z value first, followed by the coordinates, on each row. So it was ZXY format rather than XYZ. Not a big deal, perhaps, but annoying for other people who have to use the file.

At present I am using what feels like a really horrible bodge to do this (given below), but my question is: is there a good and straightforward way to write a SPDF out as XYZ, with the columns in the right order? It seems as though it ought to be easy!

Thanks for any advice.

Bodge:

```
dfOutput <- data.frame(x = coordinates(spdf)[,1], y = coordinates(spdf)[,2])
dfOutput$z <- data.frame(spdf)[,1]
write.table(dfOutput, filename, row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just

```
library(sp)
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=matrix(rnorm(30), ncol = 2), 
                               data=data.frame(z = rnorm(15)))


write.csv(cbind(coordinates(spdf), spdf@data), file = "example.csv", 
          row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hmm, good point :-) Is there a way that doesn't involve the @? I seem to remember being told that they were best avoided as the internal object structure that they represent can change from one version of a library to the next.

Comment: A quick browse through the docs didn't show a data access method a la `coordinates`. `slot(object=spdf, name = "data")` would pretty much be doing the same thing. `as.data.frame(spdf)[,1:ncol(spdf), drop = FALSE]` would work, but it's kind of unwieldy. I'm guessing that's reasonably good advice most of the time, but the general structure of `sp` objects has been pretty stable for a while.

Answer (score 2):

You can write to a .shp file using `writeOGR` from `rgdal` package. Alternatively, you could `fortify` (from `ggplot2`) your data and write that as a csv file.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a .shp file! A CSV would certainly be a route to getting a 3-column format, but going via Fortify seems almost as complex as my bodge above... this seems like it should be so simple :-)

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Noah's comment about a method like `coordinates` but for data values: The `raster` package has the `getValues()` method for returning the values of a SpatialPointsDataFrame.

```
library(raster)

spdf <- raster('raster.sdat')
write.table(
    cbind(coordinates(spdf), getValues(spdf)), 
    file = output_file, 
    col.names = c("X", "Y", "ZVALUE"),
    row.names = FALSE,
    quote = FALSE
    )
```